# Form validation doesn't working after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation

Form Validation not working correctly after form is loaded with an ajax call. How can i fix this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // $('#add_product').submit(function(e){
  $(document).on('submit', '#add_product', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post('script/test.php', {
        naam: $('#naam').val()
      })
      .done(function(response) {
        bootbox.alert(response);
        parent.fadeOut('slow');
      })
      .fail(function() {
        bootbox.alert('error');
      })
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="add_product" method="post">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="header add_product">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Productnaam*</label>
        <input maxlength="250" id="naam" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" name="naam" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr/>

    <div class="modal-footer ">
      <button class="btn btn-success completeBtn btn-lg" name="submit" type="submit" style="width: 100%;">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> Toevoegen
                    </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: did you try 'add_product' instead of '#add_product'?

Comment: @readyfreddy Tnx, but that doesn't seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

As [api.jquery](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) states,

> The `.submit()` method is a shortcut for `.on( "submit", handler )` in the first variation, and `.trigger( "submit" )` in the third.

So the behaviour of both the constructs should be the same.

Also, you are delegating your `submit` event from `#add_product` to the `document` which is low in performance cause it now has to listen for all submit events in the document.

And maybe because of the event delegation, you might have had an `e.stopPropagation` somewhere in your code which would stop the natural bubbling up of your event to the document, hence no execution of the handler.

It's much better to restrict the scope a little than listen on the document, if possible.

Try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#add_product').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post('script/test.php',
            {naam: $('#naam').val()})
            .done(function(response){
                bootbox.alert(response);
                parent.fadeOut('slow');
            })
            .fail(function(){
                bootbox.alert('error');
            })
    });
});
```

Comment: Tnx, but if i use $('#add_product').on('submit', function(e) he cant log the click and reloads the page.

Comment: I see even without the jquery it doesn't check the required fields.

Comment: It seems like the validation is not working corectly after form is loaded with an ajax call

Answer (score 0):

try to add 'return false' in your handler:

```
$(document).on('submit','#add_product',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post('script/test.php',
            {naam: $('#naam').val()})
            .done(function(response){
                bootbox.alert(response);
                parent.fadeOut('slow');
            })
            .fail(function(){
                bootbox.alert('error');
            })
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: It seems like the validation is not working corectly after form is loaded with an ajax call

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#add_product').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post('script/test.php', { naam: $('#naam').val() })
            .done(function(response) {
                bootbox.alert(response);
                parent.fadeOut('slow');
            })
            .fail(function() {
                bootbox.alert('error');
            })
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="add_product" method="post">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="header add_product">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Productnaam*</label>
                            <input maxlength="250" id="naam" type="text" required="required"
                                   class="form-control" name="naam"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        <hr/>
             
                <div class="modal-footer ">
                    <button class="btn btn-success completeBtn btn-lg" name="submit"
                            type="submit" style="width: 100%;">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> Toevoegen
                    </button>
                </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: It seems like the validation is not working corectly after form is loaded with an ajax call